# Inserting a new line in a file deletes the next two characters C++

Tags: c++

I have a file and I wish to separate items in the file by line. The indicator for the end of an item is a semicolon. So when I come across a semicolon, I want to put everything after the semicolon on a newline. And continue until i find the next semicolon and repeat.

```
char c;
fstream distances;

distances.open(argv[1]);

while(distances >> c) {
    if(c == ';') { 
        distances << endl; 
    }
}
```

This is the code inside main. It is opening the file correctly. The file says

```
i;am;testing;this
```

but after running the program the file reads:

```
i;
;
sting;
is
```

I'm not sure why it would delete the two characters following the semicolon. Unless it is using that space for \n character. If anyone could help or suggest a more efficient solution I would appreciate it.

Comment: If you're on windows, then sending `'\n'` to a text file writes two bytes, carriage return (0D) + line feed (0A).

Comment: The output operator doesn't _insert_ at the current position of a `std::fstream`, but overwrites there.

Comment: If you need to "modify" a file other to append, **always** write to a new file and then rename at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fstream` object you have is a representation of the bytes on disk. If 'insert' writes were allowed, the program would have to move every byte in the file after the insert point up by one position, essentially rewriting the file.

The only way to get an implemention of an 'insert' ability is to do it yourself, generally using a new file (you *could* do it in the same file by reading the rest of the file into memory, going back to the insert position, overwriting the character, and then writing your buffered copy of the file from before).

The reason that the *next* two characters are being overwritten is as follows:

```
// file buffer = [i][;][a][m][;][t]...
// position       ^
distances >> c;
// c = [i]
// file buffer = [i][;][a][m][;][t]...
// position          ^
distances >> c;
// c = [;]
// file buffer = [i][;][a][m][;][t]...
// position             ^
distances << endl;
```

`std::endl` writes the local line ending sequence and issues a `std::flush` to force writing. Under Windows, `endl` produces the sequence `file << '\r' << '\n' << std::flush;`

The stream position is where the `'a'` is, not where the ';' is - by reading that character you advanced the stream position past it, so it writes the `'\r'` over the `'a'` and the `'\n'` over the `'m'`.

```
// file buffer = [i][;][a][m][;][t]...
// position             ^
  distances << '\r'
// file buffer = [i][;][\r][m][;][t]...
// position                 ^
   distances << '\n'
// file buffer = [i][;][\r][\n][;][t]...
// position                     ^
distances >> c;
// c = ';'
// file buffer = [i][;][\r][\n][;][t]...
// position                        ^
```

Answer (score 3):

Despite the illusion presented by text editing software, you can't "insert" into a file. You can only read its contents, modify them in memory, then write them back out again.

Your two characters are being *replaced* by your newline which, on Windows, actually consists of a Carriage Return followed by a Line Feed.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is that you're using Microsoft Windows, where the newline sequence is two characters: a carriage return and a line feed: `\r\n`.

On Microsoft Windows a `std::endl` will write two characters: an `\r` and an `\n`.

Comment: I notice now that inserting anything will overwrite the same number of bytes in the file. Is there a way to insert without overwriting?

Comment: No. Files don't work that way. If you want to insert content in a file, you have to create a new file by reading the original file up to the point where new content gets inserted, copying everything to the new file, write the new content to the new file, then finish copying the rest of the file to the new file.

Comment: @Chris No, you have first to read in everything and then overwrite the whole file. Another option is to read and directly output to a temporary file, and replace the original one after you're done.